# How to make the annotations of a pdf permanent?

Tags: pdf, preview, adobe

I have a PDF and I have written some annotations with a pen on a tablet. I would like now these to be fixed to the PDF, so that nobody can remove the annotation or move them. Is there a simple way to do it?

On Adobe Pro I can export the file as JPG and then do a PDF but I have to do it page by page, which is long. And the quality is not that good (but that is not the biggest problem). The reason I ask this is because I correct some things on a file and I do not want the people see the previous version in any way (what is below the annotation).

I have preview or adobe pro.

Comment: Use Preview to print it to a PDF

Comment: Thanks for the help. It indeed seems to change something to the text: it is not possible to remove the annotations from the text with adobe reader. However, these are not completey merged to it as with Illustrator I still can remove them.

Comment: See if you can Merge Layers in illustrator, then save the file. This should make the annotations layer part of the background of the image, rendering it unalterable. (I don't have Illustrator on this particular Mac, so I can't check for you.)

Comment: Automator allows to export all pages of a PDF as images with adjustable resolution. In a next step it can combine these exported pixelbased images into a PDF.

Comment: Personally I prefer ghostscript. Open a terminal and use e.g.: _gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile="Pic-%d.png" input.pdf_ to convert all pages of a PDF to PNGs.

Comment: [Here](https://thefriendlytester.co.uk/2018/06/using-automator-on-a-mac-to-convert-pdf-to-images) is a screenshot of an automator workflow to acchieve the same.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. You're using annotations to make visual edits to the document. You should be able to edit the text directly with Acrobat Pro. Alternatively, you could password-protect the PDF from editing. Converting to image will prevent searching the text, reduce clarity, and significantly increase the filesize.

Comment: @slartibartfast with automator it unfortunately only takes the orginal images scanned and not the annotations. With the ghostscript it works but the quality is bad. Are there options to change the quality?

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for your comment. I see your point. However, my files are scanned images and I add annotations with a pen, so everything is essentially images. There is no text in my pdf.

Comment: Then I'd just make the corrections directly into an app that will let you open all the pages, like Inkscape, or Affinity Photo, and save back to PDF, rather than using Annotations to do something they're not meant to do.

Comment: good idea, thanks. I will do this next time

Comment: you can define the output resolution (dpi) for the exported images using _„-r value“_ e.g.: _-gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m **-r600 **…_ will create PNGs with 600dpi. Additionally you can use _-sDEVICE_ to use other file formats like JPG. Type _gs -h_ from the command line to see all formats available.

Comment: Depending on the PDF to convert it might additionally make for example sense not to export 24bit PNGs as in my first suggestion but use _-sDevice= pnggray_ for 8-bit gray Portable Network Graphics (PNG) or _-sDEVICE= jpeg_    for RGB JPEGs.

Comment: _gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -sOutputFile="Pic-%d.png" input.pdf_ will create a 300dpi grayscale PNG for each page of the input PDF